# Would I still exist if

Tags: human-biology

I've been wondering for some time, but say that my mother's egg chose another sperm cell, and a baby was eventually produced. Would I still be born, but end up with different characteristics/features?

Comment: Sorry but this is not a real question. What makes you _you_? If you have different characteristics how can you be _you_? Also, the egg does not choose sperm, where did you get that idea?

Comment: I, as in being an entity that can perceive the world. Let's Ignore the extra features like hair, eye color, etc.

Comment: Well, yes, just about _any_ sperm with any egg would produce a human being that could perceive the world. How would we decide if that's 'you' or not?

Comment: I was hoping someone would have an answer to that.

Comment: consciousness and awareness and in fact a brain develops long after fertilization.. i hope that clears your doubt

Comment: @terdon This is a legitimate philosophy question. Not biology, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every sperm that fertilises an egg there are millions/billions/"a sh**load" that don't make it. Within that pool of unused sperm there is considerable genetic variation. If we assume that DNA is the only factor which makes "you you" then the chance of picking one of those  sperm and it having the exact same DNA is small. Of course environment also has a large effect so even two identical sperm and egg combinations would produce two people with different physical and mental attributes.

If this does not answer your question then this is not really a biological question though and should really be on the philosophy SE.